# When i take the adjacency matrix of a graph and convert it to a SymPy matrix, the values of matrix get many zeros decimals and i dont understand why

Tags: python

I took the adjacency matrix of a graph, then converted it to a sympy matrix. Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
E = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [4,1]]
G.add_edges_from(E)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
m = sp.Matrix(A)
print((m.table(sp.StrPrinter())))
```

And what i get:

```
Output:
[             0.0, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000]
[1.00000000000000,              0.0,              0.0, 1.00000000000000]
[1.00000000000000,              0.0,              0.0,              0.0]
[1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000,              0.0,              0.0]
```

What happened and how can i convert all these values to integers? I guess that i can make a loop and and convert them all with `int(i)` but there must be a shorter version. A friend run the same code and his values were integers from the start

Comment: What if you use `print(A)`? Or just `print(nx.adjacency_matrix(G))`?

Comment: It works with your first suggestion. But i still dont understand why this happened and also if i want to do operations on the matrix i want it to be a sympy object

Answer (score 0):

This is happening I think because the type of your matrix is a floaat (either 64 or 32 bit). To make it `ints` you can just use the `dtype` parameter like so:

```
>>> m = sp.Matrix(A, dtype=int)
>>> m
Matrix([
[0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0]])
```